# Loop stuck while calculating the nearest neighbour

Tags: python, loops, indexing, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to print out the list of nearest neighbours. I should be getting a list of length 12; however, the list I am getting is of shorter length. When I print out the values for the variable 'a', it is getting stuck at the last element of the list 'path'. I've been trying to debug it, but couldn't find why the value of 'a' is not following the same pattern and why I can't get the other elements.

G is a graph with 11 nodes in total, and what I should be getting is G.NNA(3) = [3, 4, 0, 10, 2, 8, 1, 7, 5, 11, 6, 9]. I am getting the list up until the eighth index [3, 4, 0, 10, 2, 8, 1, 7, 5].

I put print statements inside the two 'if' statements, and the value 'a' clearly gets stuck. It would be amazing if I could fix it. Thanks in advance!

```
def NNA(self, start):

        path = [start] # Initialize the path that starts with the given point

        usedNodes = [start] # List for used nodes

        currentNode = start

        a = 1
        
        while len(path) < self.n and a < self.n:
            distances = self.dists[currentNode] # self.dists[3] = [4, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2] and the indeces correspond to the nodes
            nextNode = distances.index(sorted(distances)[a]) # Gets the next node
            if nextNode not in usedNodes :
                a = 1
                path.append(nextNode)
                usedNodes.append(nextNode)
                currentNode = nextNode
                print(currentNode, a)
            elif nextNode in usedNodes:
                a = a + 1 # Check the next smallest value
                print(currentNode, a)
        self.perm = path
        print(path)
```

```
# Here is the output
4 1
4 2
0 1
10 1
10 2
2 1
8 1
8 2
1 1
7 1
5 1 # gets stuck at 5
5 2
5 3
5 4
5 5
5 6
5 7
5 8
5 9
5 10
5 11
5 12
[3, 4, 0, 10, 2, 8, 1, 7, 5] # expecting [3, 4, 0, 10, 2, 8, 1, 7, 5, 11, 6, 9]
```

Comment: please provide a minimun reproductible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example